# iOS : Share with UIActivityViewController & Default applications

Tags: ios, file, share, uiactivityviewcontroller, uti

*iOS 13.1.2 & Xamarin.Mono 6.6.0.104*

I have an application which handles its own data formats.
I added the DocumentType and the Exported UTI declaration in the plist.
(I followed this link to do so: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1587/_index.html)

When I tap on a file with my extension, I can see my application, but only in the "..." (More) button, not in the default list.

Is there a way to have my application at the same level as the Messages app without having to add it manually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add this:

```
<key>LSHandlerRank</key>
<string>Default</string>
```

Under the CFBundleType section.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the handler rank did not change anything for me as I already used Owner for this property.

I may have found why I had such a behavior like that.
It seems that it was due to my recent update to iOS 13... I reset my device and everything looks ok...

Thanks for your answer!